# Custom Laravel Registration Email

Tags: laravel, fortify

I have built an authentication system on laravel using Fortify, sadly the email templates is kinda boring so I want to change them. but I couldn't find where the template is located in their documentation. I would love to get some help.

Answer (score 3):

Fortify is using the default Laravel Notifications template that you can easily overwrite using your own Notifications.

Here is a clear and well explained video tutorial on [How to Translate/Customize Laravel Auth Default Emails](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c01k5Zo_CuI)